# In After Effects, when I scale two layers at once they scale at different rates?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, resize

I am trying to resize two mov layers together. I would usually select both layers, hold shift to maintain their shape and drag the scale slider or layer corner inwards/outward. When I tried this the two objects changed scale at different rates and ended up quite different to each other? this only occurs when mov files are in the composition; on a separate comp with solids scaling works fine. How do you resize two mov at the same time?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing they have different z positions but it's hard to know without seeing the file.

Comment: That's what i thought but they aren't 3d

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of the layers?

Comment: Well I can't reproduce this at all.. Just to clarify, when you say they scale at different rates, do the actual numbers scale correctly?

Comment: Ok, I think I may understand your problem... [this](http://recordit.co/H8FmAVzUIX) for example, **IS** scaling correctly. Is that what is happening and *not* what you want?

Comment: that is exactly what is happening!!

Comment: do you know why they aren't maintaining their size relative to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the layers **are** scaling at the same rate. If you look at the actual scale values. For example, if you have one layer at 100% scale and another at 90% scale, then select both and resize to 50%, the layers will be at 50% scale and 40% scale, so they have both had their scale reduced by 50% of their total 100%, not 50% of their current scale.

You can see the default behaviour here:

[image]

As far as I'm aware this is just how After Effects work and you can't change it. There are 2 main ways to get around this:

#### 1. Pre-compose.

Select all the layers you want to scale, right click and select **Pre-Compose...**

#### 2. Null Layer.

Create a new Null Layer (**Layer → New → Null Object**). Select all the layers you want to scale and parent them to the Null Object (drag the little icon under 'Parent' in the layers/timeline to the Null layer).

Answer (score 0):

File>Scripts>Scale composition.jsx